# How to show first image of gallery on hover, in different element

Tags: javascript, image, show, mouseover, mouseout

I'm stuck with this for a while and can't  find any solution helping me out.

To give an idea of what's going on: I have a `li` containing an `a` element and a gallery `div` which will show up in `#thumb` on click on `a`. ( I cut this part out of the code for now)

**I want the first image of the gallery to be visible when hovering `a`. If there is no content in the gallery, i want nothing to happen.**

How can I achieve this in plain js? I got quite far but I'm missing the js knowledge (hence all the var's i guess :-). Help is very much appreciated.

The gallery's are automatically generated, so the amount of gallery-#'s depends on the amount of gallery's added via CMS.

[JS Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/luuuuuuuuk/ry1yjn8w/12/)

```js
var hoverThis = document.getElementsByClassName("project-item");
var galleryId = document.querySelector(".open-gallery").getAttribute("href");
var getFirstImg = document.querySelector(galleryId).firstElementChild.getAttribute("href");
var thumb = document.getElementById('thumb');
var content = getFirstImg.includes("http");


if (content == true) {

  hoverThis.addEventListener("mouseover", function(e) {

    e.target.thumb.innerHTML = '<img src="' + getFirstImg + '" class="thumb-img">"';

  }, false);

  hoverThis.addEventListener("mouseout", function(e) {

    e.target.thumb.innerHTML = '';

  }, false);

} else {
  console.log('empty')
};
```

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
}

#thumb {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background: beige;
}

.hidden {
  display: none
}

img {
  height 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class='project-item'>
    <a href="#gallery-1" class="open-gallery">
      <span>01.11.17</span>
    </a>
    <div id="gallery-1" class="hidden">
      <a href="http://placehold.it/150x150">Image 3</a>
      <a href="g1-second-image">Image 2</a>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class='project-item'>
    <a href="#gallery-2" class="open-gallery">
      <span>02.11.17</span>
    </a>
    <div id="gallery-2" class="hidden">
      <!-- empty gallery -->
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class='project-item'>
    <a href="#gallery-3" class="open-gallery">
      <span>03.11.17</span>
    </a>
    <div id="gallery-3" class="hidden">
      <a href="http://placehold.it/200x20
      0">Image 1</a>
      <a href="g3-second-image">Image 2</a>
      <a href="g3-third-image">Image 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="thumb-wrap">
  <figure id="thumb">
  </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: error in code snippet : {
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: hoverThis.addEventListener is not a function",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 75,
  "colno": 13
}

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName("project-item") returns an array-like object, with html elements, so you can, and should loop through it, to get desired hoverThis var(s).

Comment: Yes thanks, that helped!